# Saving states across JFrames

Tags: java, swing

I am trying the save the state of a previous frame and then carry it over to the other frame. More like saving the data of the textfields and areas so that when i press next button some text fields,and variables will be initialized in the next forms Labels and when you press back your previous data will still remain in your form inteface.Pls help

More like data binding but across different forms

Answer (score 3):

You can use any varible for that, and pass it as parameter to every JFrame you create.

But it sounds more like you want to use a CardLayout for your JFrame and use different cards that can be shown for the user. See [How to use CardLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

Comment: Yes, about using Card Layout. How can I use that in a netbeans environment. I don't want to have to code all my already designed component manually, how can i use the netbeans drag and drop to achieve that

Comment: @nnanna: That's another question. I have no idea since I have never used Netbeans.

Comment: what ide is possible to achieve that.

Comment: *"what ide is possible to achieve that."*  Netbeans.  I don't use it, but I know it is possible to use Netbeans with the GUI designer & any layout you can add to the class-path.  But until you figure how to use your IDE, you might look to learning how to code these things in Java.  That knowledge will make using a GUI builder a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to create a wizard like UI, you should look up [Sun(oracle)tutorial here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/swing/wizard/).

Answer (score 0):

Use something like Java's [XMLEncoder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/XMLEncoder.html).